# Derivation of V(s) and Q(s, a) from the performance objective in MDP's

Tags: math, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization, reinforcement-learning

I'm considering the paper [Policy Optimization with Model-based Explorations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.07350.pdf), section 2 on the derivation of V(s) and Q(s, a)

> The goal of the agent is to find the policy π∗ from a restricted
>   family of parametrized policy functions that maximizes its
>   performance,

[image]

The paper states in equation 2 where the performance objective is defined as follows:

> where J(π) is the performance objective defined as

[image]

Next, the authors create this arbitrary function (eq 3), defined as:

> For convenience, let ρ
>   π
>   (s) denote the
>   (unnormalized) discounted cumulated state distribution induced by policy π,

[image]

And for some reason they use this to get the following:

> then the performance objective can rewrite as

[image]

Furthermore, they find the following based on the previous derivation.

[image]

[image]

My questions are the following:

1. Could anyone explain to me, how to construct this rho function
2. How they construct the new J function?
3. Based on the new J function, how do they construct the Q from that?
4. Also, I've not seen this notation for V before, what do the authors do here?

Comment: You may want to have a look at TRPO paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477.pdf The "Preliminaries" section explains what you are asking (which is something already proved in some old papers, also referenced in TRPO paper). Be aware that they use "eta" instead of "J".